# OperationContract when set to one way does not accept http headers

Tags: asp.net, rest

I am trying to create a one way operation on my Rest service but it seems it doesn't accept 
headers for OneWay service!!

I define it one way operation like this

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
```

While it works fine for non one way operations.

Is it true? Or I am in mistake.

Comment: what do you mean by *one way*?

Comment: When I set IsOneWay to true for OperationContract

Comment: Did you try something else to make async calls?

Comment: I started trying for that, then I found this way that works as I expected so I stopped searching for async.